# How to sort IP address stored as a varchar in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, sorting

How to sort IP address stored as a varchar in table, I am trying to sort the records and if i ORDER BY column_name asc. I get the sorted value but i dont know whether that is the right way to do that to sort IP address stored as varchar.

So pleas suggest me if the above approach is good or if it is wrong pleas suggest the way to do that.

DB : Oracle

Thanks

Comment: Sample Data, your select statement, expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to sort IP address stored as a varchar in table, I am trying to sort the records and if i ORDER BY column_name asc.

You are sorting by a **string** and not **number**.

You could have stored the **IP address** into **4 different NUMBER columns**. Now, that you have a single column for IP address with all the 4 fields together, you are left with delimited string manipulation.

You could do it in two ways:

**1. SUBSTR and TO_NUMBER**

For example,

```
SELECT IP
FROM table_name
ORDER BY to_number(SUBSTR(IP,1,instr(IP,'.')-1)) ,
  to_number(SUBSTR(IP,instr(IP,'.')         +1, instr(IP,'.',1,2) - instr(IP,'.') - 1)),
  to_number(SUBSTR(IP,instr(IP,'.',1,2)     +1, instr(IP,'.',1,3) - instr(IP,'.',1,2) - 1)),
  to_number(SUBSTR(IP,instr(IP,'.',1,3)     +1))
/
```

**2. REGEXP_SUBSTR and TO_NUMBER**

For example,

```
SELECT IP
FROM table_name
ORDER BY TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (IP, '[[:digit:]]+', 1, 1)) ASC ,
  TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (IP, '[[:digit:]]+', 1, 2)) ASC ,
  TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (IP, '[[:digit:]]+', 1, 3)) ASC ,
  TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (IP, '[[:digit:]]+', 1, 4)) ASC 
/
```

The simple SUBSTR approach would be a bit faster, since REGEXP is a CPU intensive operation.